# Angular: .ts file code optimization

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on angular 4, my .ts of a component is too long (850 lines). I have already moved the redundant code to a function and also separated out the template. How can I optimize the code more?  Can I create a new component and move my code there? Or any other way, please guide.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create a new component and move my code there

Yes you can. This is what a component based architecture should be for. You can extract parts of your HTML strucure to a new component and render it inside another component. For example:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav
        #drawer
        class="sidenav"
        fixedInViewport="true"
        [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
        [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
        [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)"
    >
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a
                mat-list-item
                href="#"
            >
                Link 1
            </a>
            <a
                mat-list-item
                href="#"
            >
                Link 2
            </a>
            <a
                mat-list-item
                href="#"
            >
                Link 3
            </a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
            <button
                type="button"
                aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
                mat-icon-button
                (click)="drawer.toggle()"
                *ngIf="isHandset$ | async"
            >
                <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <span>life-quality-web</span>
        </mat-toolbar>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

You can easily move the part from the mat-sidenav to a new component:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">

   // component: my-sidenav
   <my-sidenav></my-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
            <button
                type="button"
                aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
                mat-icon-button
                (click)="drawer.toggle()"
                *ngIf="isHandset$ | async"
            >
                <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <span>life-quality-web</span>
        </mat-toolbar>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Also you can move logic to services, that is even the way angular style guide suggest: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#delegate-complex-component-logic-to-services